# Provider error '8007203e' The search filter cannot be recognized. in Functions.asp, line 669

Tags: vbscript, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I'm working on a project which is written on vbscript . I'm getting error at Provider error '8007203e'  The search filter cannot be recognized.  in Functions.asp, line 669 and I don't know how to log LDAP errors . Anyone has any clue how to log LDAP error or any link , document will be fine . Please help

**Functions.asp**

```
Dim strServerName, strQuery, strUID, struid2, struid3, strUID4, sqlstring
Dim field, oConn, oCommand, oRS, rs, item, UserID, sec, firstname, lastname, mail, phone

        strUID4 = Lcase(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))

    
        strServerName = "dc=***,dc=***,dc=***,dc=***"
    
        set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        set oCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        
        oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
        oConn.Properties ("User ID")="***\***"
        oConn.Properties ("Password")="***"
        oConn.Properties ("Encrypt Password")=True
        
        oConn.Open "Ads Provider"
        
        strUID4 = Replace(strUID4,"***\","")
        sqlstring  = "(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=organizationalPerson)(cn=" & struid4 &") "
        
        set oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConn  
        strQuery= "<LDAP://" & strServername &">;(&" & sqlstring &");givenname,sn,mail,cn,company,department,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,telephoneNumber,displayName"
        
        oCommand.CommandText = strQuery
        oCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1            
        set oRS = oCommand.Execute      

        If NOT oRS.EOF Then
            Session("SecID") = strUID4
            Session("FirstName") = oRS.fields("givenname")
            Session("LastName") = oRS.fields("sn")
            Session("eMailadress") = oRS.fields("mail")
            Session("Phone") = oRS.fields("telephoneNumber")
            Session("Location") = oRS.fields("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")
            Session("department") = oRS.fields("department")
            Session("Company") = oRS.fields("company")
            Session("DisplayName") = oRS.Fields("displayName")
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here or how to log the LDAP exceptions , errors

Comment: Output `strQuery` to see what it contains, chances are it's not what you expect.

Comment: Would also recommend `Option Explicit` at the top of your script so you can see which variables haven't been defined correctly, at the moment `strUID4` and `struid4 ` are looking suspect. It's also worth noting that these are basic things you should be trying before posting on [so], the fact the ADSI query is complaining about the search filter should be enough to tell you that there is an issue with how `strQuery` is built.

Comment: Hello @Lankymart you are right . strQuery is wrong . Now I found my strQuery is (&objectClass=user)(objectCategory=organizationalPerson)(cn=abcvdfr);givenname,sn,mail,cn,company,department,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,telephoneNumber,displayName but now set oRS = oCommand.Execute is giving error

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP, an `AND` filter must be in the form of:

`(&(objectClass=xxx)(cn=abcd))`

If you need more complex filters, I suggest you look at [RFC 4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515)

Comment: thank you @Ludovic for your reply . I found my ldap server using nslookup from cmd xyzdfdf.zzz.ff.cfcf.bbb  and i created this query <LDAP://dc=xyzdfdf,dc=zzz,dc=ff,dc=cfcf,dc=bbb>;(&objectClass=user)(objectCategory=organizationalPerson)(cn=abcd);givenname,sn,mail,cn,company,department,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,telephoneNumber,displayName" and I'm getting error One or more errors occurred during processing of command. Can you tell me what is wrong in my ldap query

Comment: also i tried dsquery but it's not working at all from command prompt

Comment: I think you are not paying attention to the filter syntax. It should be `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=organizationalPerson)(cn=abcd))`